# Holomorphic and analytic functions in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, analytic-functions

A function f:C→C is said to be holomorphic at a point if there is some neighborhood around that point on which function is differentiable.

The function f:C→C is said to be analytic at a point if around that point there is a neighborhood on which f can be represented Taylor series expansion which converges to f.
I have seen these definitions from Wikipedia but haven't seen in any book ,so can anybody provide me reference of a standard book where I can find the same definitions.
Secondly how the concept of holomorphicity and analyticity coincides in complex analysis?which class is bigger in general?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Greene and Krantz is another standard but is a bit advanced.

Comment: Okay thanks will go through it possibly but right now I wanted know whether two definitions are correct? Which I found correct hopefully......

Comment: The two definitions are equivalent. You can prove one from the other!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find them in Reinhold Remmert's *Theory of complex functions* or in Serge Lang's *Complex Analysis*, for instance. In those textbooks you will also find a proof of the fact that every holomorphic function is analytic, a highly non-trivial fact. On the other hand, it is quite easy to prove that every analytic function is holomorphic.

Comment: Is pdf available of both the books?

Comment: Why don't you do a Google search?

Comment: Yeah I have got it.......thanks for your cooperation

Comment: I'm glad I could help.